# SQL to create a single row that incorporates several look-up values from a join table with several associated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if my question is even phrased properly as I tried SO's suggested posts  but didn't quite find what I was looking for.

In a nutshell I am trying to show which 'areas' a citizen belongs to. Every citizen will be associated with 3 areas: `Borough`, `Neighbourhood` and `Natural Neighbourhood`. The citizen is linked to each area by a join table.

I need just ONE row (for each citizen in the database) that shows all of the areas they belong to.

The goal is this:

```
CitizenId  CitizenName  Borough     Neighbourhood       NaturalNeighbourhood
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Fred         Elmbridge   Esher & Claygate    Esher
```

The tables involved are shown below.

**Citizen**

```
ID  Name
1   Fred
```

**AreaCategory**

```
ID  Value
1   root
2   Division
3   Borough
4   Neighbourhood
5   Natural Neighbourhood
```

**AreaType**

```
ID  FK_AreaCategory   Value
1   3                 Elmbridge
2   4                 Esher & Claygate
3   5                 Esher
```

**CitizenAreas**

```
FK_Citizen   FK_AreaType
1            3
1            4
1            5
```

No doubt simple for someone who knows their stuff but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks @podiluska. I now have this which is slightly re-worked to use the exact table names in my database. I originally received the error:

"Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE."

I then checked and saw that the database was showing as SQL Server 2000 compatible. When I changed this to SQL Server 2008 compatible everything worked.

```
USE ACRM
GO
select 
   *
from
(
select c.ID, FirstName, at.Value as area, ac.value as category
from
ACRM.DBO.ActiveCitizen c
    inner join ACRM.DBO.ActiveCitizenAreas ca on c.Id = ca.FK_ActiveCitizen
    inner join ACRM.DBO.AreaType at on ca.FK_AreaType = at.ID
    inner join ACRM.DBO.AreaCategory ac on at.FK_AreaCategory = ac.id
) v
pivot (max(area) for category in (Borough, Neighbourhood, [Natural Neighbourhood])) p
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot`

```
select 
    *
from
(
select c.ID, Name, at.Value as area, ac.value as category
from
    citizen c
        inner join citizenAreas ca on c.Id = ca.FK_Citizen
        inner join areatype at on ca.FK_AreaType = at.ID
        inner join areaCategory ac on at.FK_AreaCategory = ac.id
) v
pivot (max(area) for category in (Borough, Neighbourhood, [natural neighbourhood])) p
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm glad I posted... I didn't even know about 'pivot', I must do some tutorials on it. I am getting the following error - I'm on SQL Server 2008. "Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value..."

Comment: @user975516 You may have mistyped. This should be fine in SQL 2008, unless you have set the compatibility level to SQL 2000 or something.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did cut and paste and I can't see any differences although I did rename the tables to match. I'll edit my original question to show what I have now. Thanks again.

Comment: @user975516 No. There's no typo. What is the DB Compatibility level of this database?

Comment: Once again thank you @podiluska! The compatibility level was 2000 - I guess it must have started off as an SQL Server 2000 database. I have changed the compatibility and all is working as you suggest. My sincere thanks.